# Research Paper on Music Style of A R Rahman

Tags: style, reference-request, filmi

I am looking for a scholarly article/ research paper on the analysis of music style and the influence of Indian composer A R Rahman. I searched [google scholar (I have searched the first 7 pages using related keywords.)](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=60&q=a%20r%20rahman%20music%20journal%20research&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1) but could not yield anything substantial.

Answer (score 3):

I found one article that might be promising. I accessed it through the online database Academic Search Premier, through my University library.

Citation:

> Beaster-Jones, Jayson. “A.R. Rahman and the Aesthetic Transformation
> of Indian Film Scores.” South Asian Popular Culture, vol. 15, no. 2/3,
> July 2017, pp. 155–171. EBSCOhost, doi:10.1080/14746689.2017.1407551.

Abstract:

> Orchestral scores in Hindi cinema have been virtually ignored both by
> fans and scholars: they have received little attention from Indian
> music and film critics and are only infrequently a subject for
> commentary. Despite the lack of respect for film scores, however,
> music director A.R. Rahman carefully crafted his scores to generate
> musical narratives that operate in tandem with film narratives. In
> order to illustrate how Rahman’s film scores of the late 1990s and
> early 2000s marked an inflection point for background music in later
> Indian films, this article compares the background scores of the
> filmsTaal(1999) andSwades(2004). The article traces the development of
> musical themes in these films and Rahman’s later shift in
> compositional approach, suggesting that later composers in mainstream
> andhatkecinema deployed new tactics in their film scores, such as the
> development of musical themes unrelated to the song melodies composed
> for the film. These changes in background scoring practices provide
> new incentives for audiences to attend to musical sound in the
> narrative, heralding the commercial success of multiplex films of the
> 2010s, even as they blurred the boundaries between film song and film
> score.